# Adaptar layout a la resolución de la pantalla en que se esté mostrando

Tags: java, android, xml

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer que un layout se adapte a la pantalla en que se muestra, ya que tengo uno que, aunque se muestra bien horizontalmente en TV, al hacerlo en el móvil las letras se solapan. ¿Hay maner de hacer que el tamaño de letra se adapte a la pantalla para que pueda verse en su sitio sea cual se la pantalla?

Answer (score 3):

Podrías intentar con el `ConstraintLayout` para hacer `responsive` tus pantallas:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bsi_1.nominabsi.ActBusquedaEmpleados"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Así como esta en el XML que te dí de ejemplo, se debería adaptar a cualquier pantalla. ojo, es forzoso que sea `ConstaintLayout`, y que utilices la propiedad `infer constraints` en el layout que herede desde el `ConstraintLayout`.
[image: ejemplo]
Si necesitas más información, te anexo [la guía con la que yo aprendí](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: mis respetos en diseño (Y)

Comment: gracias ^^ realmente paso mucho tiempo aprendiendo con componentes y demás jajaja

Answer (score -1):

Lo que se hace en Android es definir diferentes layouts para diferentes tamaños de pantalla. Ademas en Android Studio hay una funcion que te permite visualizar como se vera la app en diferentes dispositivos y configuraciones de pantalla.

Mas informacion.. [Compatibilidad con diferentes pantallas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es-419)